# How to optimize a macro used to insert text from a dynamic range from Microsoft Excel into Word

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have an Excel macro written which:

1. Opens up a specific Word document
2. Checks if the Excel named range is empty
3. If not empty, checks if the Word bookmark range exists
4. Goes back to the Excel named range and checks if the cell is empty besides it

4.a. If the cell beside it is empty, the cell from from Step 2replaces the Word bookmark
range

4.b If the cell beside it is not empty, it stores the dynamic range of cells into a variable

5. A For loop is used to cycle through the dynamic range of cells and insert them one by one in separate bullet points like so:

- Cell 1.Value
- Cell 2.Value
- Cell 3.Value

So my code works, but I'm unable to change it into a Subroutine to call it multiple times throughout the macro

Here is my code:

```
Sub GenerateWordDoc()
Dim theApp As Object
On Error Resume Next
MacScript "tell application id ""com.microsoft.Word"" to activate"
Err.Clear
Set theApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
theApp.Visible = True
Dim doc As Object
With theApp
 .Visible = True
 .Activate
End With
Dim docName As String
docName = 'test-doc.docx'
Set doc = theApp.Documents.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "/" & docName, ReadOnly:=True)

' Looping through cells and adding it to Bullet lists
 If IsEmpty(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("excel_dynamic_range")) Then
        Call ReplaceBookmarkWithSingleString(doc, "List is empty", "word_bookmark1")
    Else
        If doc.Bookmarks.Exists("word_bookmark1") Then
            doc.Bookmarks("word_bookmark1").Range.Select
            With theApp.Selection
                .EndKey Unit:=wdLine ' go to end of line after selection 
                .TypeText "List:"
                ' If there is no value in adjacent cell to the right
                If IsEmpty(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("excel_dynamic_range").Offset(, 1)) 
                Then
                    .TypeParagraph
                    .Range.ListFormat.ListIndent
                    .TypeText Sheets("Sheet1").Range("excel_dynamic_range").Value
                Else
                    Dim multiple_option_values3() As Variant
                    multiple_option_values3 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("excel_dynamic_range", Range("excel_dynamic_range").End(xlToRight)).Value
                    Dim R3 As Long
                    Dim C3 As Long
                    For R3 = 1 To UBound(multiple_option_values3, 1)
                        For C3 = 1 To UBound(multiple_option_values3, 2)
                            .TypeParagraph
                            If C3 = 1 Then
                                .Range.ListFormat.ListIndent
                            End If
                            .TypeText multiple_option_values3(R3, C3)
                        Next C3
                    Next R3
                End If
            End With
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

So when I change the Looping through cells and insert into bullet point above into a Subroutine, passing in the `theApp` variable as a param isn't executing the code at all:

```
Sub ReplaceBookmarkMultipleOptionsBulletList(ByVal theApp As Object, doc As Object, bookmarkName As String, excelRange As Range, initialBulletText As String, indentBulletList As Boolean)
  Debug.Print theApp
  Debug.Print doc
  Debug.Print bookmarkName
  If doc.Bookmarks.Exists(bookmarkName) Then
        Debug.Print "bookmark exists in Word"
        doc.Bookmarks(bookmarkName).Range.Select
        theApp.Visible = True
        With theApp.Selection
             Debug.Print theApp.Selection
            .EndKey Unit:=wdLine
             .TypeParagraph
             .TypeText "change the text again"
            If excelRange.Count = 1 Then
                .TypeParagraph
                If indentBulletList = True Then
                    .Range.ListFormat.ListIndent
                End If
                .TypeText Sheets("Sheet 1").excelRange.Value
            Else
                Dim multiple_option_values() As Variant
                multiple_option_values = excelRange.Value
                Dim R As Long
                Dim C As Long
                For R = 1 To UBound(multiple_option_values, 1)
                    For C = 1 To UBound(multiple_option_values, 2)
                        .TypeParagraph
                        If C = 1 And indentBulletList = True Then
                            .Range.ListFormat.ListIndent
                        End If
                        .TypeText multiple_option_values(R, C)
                    Next C
                Next R
            End If
        End With
  End If
End Sub
```

How can I fix or optimize the macro above to insert the values from a dynamic range of cells into a Word doc?

Comment: Objects aren't passed `ByVal`, you should use `ByRef`.

Comment: If you pass the Document, then you don't need to also pass the Word Application. Since both are tied together if you pass one, the other automatically comes along. You can access the Application by doing `Document.Application` and you can access the Document in the `Application.Documents` collection. You don't need both arguments.

Comment: I see a possible error in `Sheets("Sheet 1")`. Are you sure its `"Sheet 1"` and not `"Sheet1"`?

Comment: @Toddleson  When you pass an object byRef you get the original pointer to the object.  If you assign a new object to this pointer then you overwrite the original object.  When you pass an object ByVal you get a copy of the pointer to the original object.  If you assign a new object the  byval pointer the byval pointer gets the object  and the original object is not changed.

Comment: @Toddleson I changed the sub to remove the Application parameter, and fixed a few things with the errors you mentioned, but the sub seems to hit an error when it reaches the `doc.Application.Visible = true` line. 

However, this works when the code is not being called in a Sub. I'm on a MacBook btw if that changes anything.

Comment: Check if `doc Is Nothing`. That's the only reason I can think of for why there would be an error with that line.

Comment: @Toddleson checked with `If doc is Nothing Then` and the block didn't run, but also the `doc.Bookmarks(bookName).Range.Select` works so I'm not sure why the `doc.Application` methods aren't working